# How to render new images in PrimeNg Galleria which are browsed through PrimeNG File-Upload

Tags: file-upload, primeng, angular11

I am trying to bind the the array of image files browsed through primeNg file-upload to the primeNg gallaria.

Below is the html code -

```html
<p-fileUpload #fubauto1 mode="basic" multiple="multiple" name="demo1[]" accept="image/*" maxFileSize="maxImageFileSize" 
    (onSelect)="onSelectImages($event)" chooseLabel="Select Images"></p-fileUpload>
    <p-galleria [(value)]="previews" [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions" [containerStyle]="{'max-width': '640px'}"
     [numVisible]="3"> 
      <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
          <img [src]="item.imagePath" style="width: 100%; display: block;" />
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="thumbnail" let-item>
          <div class="p-grid p-nogutter p-justify-center">
              <img [src]="item.imagePath" style="display: block;width: 50%" />
          </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption" let-item>
          <h4 style="margin-bottom: .5rem; color: #ffffff;">{{item?.title}}</h4>
          <p>{{item.alt}}</p>
      </ng-template>
    </p-galleria>
```

angular ts code as below -

```js
 onSelectImages(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.currentFiles;

    this.previews = [];
    if (this.selectedFiles && this.selectedFiles[0]) {
      const numberOfFiles = this.selectedFiles.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.previews.push(e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFiles[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried to display images in simple image html element, it's working but when attaching to the gallaria it is not working.

also check for the working of gallaria, yes it is working when input given before initialization of gallaria but when initialization of gallaria gets completed and we bind browsed images array it is not working.

can any one help me for the above problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

Hope below answer helps someone. After uploading the image, don't directly push the image and images will not get updated. Create another variable named imagestemp, push the images and copy it to the main one(this.previews)where images are binded to galleria.

**Code:**

```
imagestemp: any[] = [];
 onSelectImages(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.currentFiles;

    this.previews = [];
    if (this.selectedFiles && this.selectedFiles[0]) {
      const numberOfFiles = this.selectedFiles.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.imagestemp.push(e.target.result);
        };
    this.previews=[...imagestemp]
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFiles[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```